# Answering a duplicate question

Tags: discussion

Tbis is one of those *oops* moments. I've answered [Short story where humans receive false distress signal, lured into galactic federation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81748/short-story-where-humans-receive-false-distress-signal-lured-into-galactic-fede) without stopping to think that it's a duplicate (the OP actually linked the previous duplicate).

Should I delete my answer, answer the previous duplicate and finally vote to close the question I initially answered? Or do I vote to close the previous question, or just shrug and leave things as they are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you do anything, vote to close the old question as a duplicate.**

Just because two questions are duplicates doesn't mean we have to close the new question as a dupe of the old one. We make the question with the best answers the "canonical" question, and closes others as a dupe of that, regardless of the order in which they were posted.

In this case, the newer question has an answer (with three votes, which you'd lose if you delete/reposted it), and the older question doesn't. Ergo, it's the old question that should be closed, if any.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I see the mods have already closed the earlier question as a duplicate.